# Java JNA Invalid Memory Access

Tags: java, delphi, dll, jna

I have a DLL which is written in Delphi (do not have the source code, but only the API). Here is the DLL function I am trying to invoke through Java using the JNA (version 5.4.0)

[image: DLL Function]

The following shows how my Java code looks like.

```
public interface FPrintDLL extends StdCallLibrary {
    FPrintDLL INSTANCE = Native.load("FPrintDLL", FPrintDLL.class);
    int OPEN_TCPIP(WString ipAddress, int port, int deviceIndex, WString serialKey);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FPrintDLL fPrintDLL = FPrintDLL.INSTANCE;
    WString ipAddress = new WString("192.170.1.3");
    WString serialKey = new WString("12345678");
    int deviceIndex = 4004;
    int port = 9100;

    int connectResult = fPrintDLL.OPEN_TCPIP(ipAddress, port, deviceIndex, serialKey); // Line 81
}
```

Everything loads fine, the problem is I am getting the following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:426)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.OPEN_TCPIP(Unknown Source)
at HelloJNA.main(HelloJNA.java:81)
```

According to the exception log the problem occurred because of the ints. According to the method signature it doesn't use any pointers/references. So I am not sure what exactly the problem is.

**Note** - I managed to successfully run this function under the same conditions (the OS, JAVA, DLL architectures are listed below) using the following C# the code,

```
[DllImport(FPRINT_DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int OPEN_TCPIP([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string ipAddress,
        int tcpPort,
        int deviceIndex,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string serialKey);
```

I mentioned this because to confirm that the given API for OPEN_TCPIP is correct. Now I want to make a direct interaction between Java and the DLL. (not using some kind of a wrapper class)

The DLL is a 32-bit DLL and I am trying it on a 32-bit JVM, Windows10 64bit.
FYI I tried the following sources (listed few) but couldn't work this out.

[DLL issues and Invalid Memory Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078826/dll-issues-and-invalid-memory-access)

[Java Native Access code Error: “Invalid memory access”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383453/java-native-access-code-error-invalid-memory-access)

[Function call returns java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849222/jna-library-function-call-returns-java-lang-error-invalid-memory-access)

[JNA: java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703083/jna-java-lang-error-invalid-memory-access)

[Java use JNA call dll error:Invalid memory access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625733/java-use-jna-call-dll-errorinvalid-memory-access)  (All the required DLLs are in the same directory)

[JNA Exception in thread “main” java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057959/jna-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-error-invalid-memory-accessunknown-so)

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Delphi's `WideString` is a managed type that is not compatible with non-Delphi compilers. Since you don't have the source code for the DLL, you can't change it to use a different type that is more friendly to Java. That being said, `WideString` is a wrapper for a COM `BSTR`, which is why your C# code works. For Java, your only option is to have JNA call Win32 BSTR functions (`SysAllocString()` and `SysFreeString() `) and pass the raw pointers into the DLL. Or else wrap the DLL in another DLL that exposes a more friendly interface for Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature requires a `BSTR` which requires memory allocation on the C side.  You are passing a `WString` which is causing the Invalid memory access.

Allocate memory for the BSTR arguments like this:

```
BSTR ipAddress = OleAuto.INSTANCE.SysAllocString("192.170.1.3");
BSTR serialKey = OleAuto.INSTANCE.SysAllocString("12345678");
```

Once you are finished with the `BSTR`s you must release the memory:

```
OleAuto.INSTANCE.SysFreeString(ipAddress);
OleAuto.INSTANCE.SysFreeString(serialKey);
```